# How to split the csv with \n with condition

Tags: python, regex, pandas, csv

I have csv and need to split the second column with \n

```
name,address
711-2880,Mankato\n96522\n(257) 563-7401
971-2880,CA\n965\n(01) 563-7401\nNebraska
```

Expected Out

```
name,address
711-2880,Mankato
711-2880,96522
711-2880,(257) 563-7401
971-2880,CA
971-2880,965
971-2880,(01) 563-7401
971-2880,Nebraska
```

I am able to read the csv and able to convert to dataframe with 2 columns but struggling with seperation \n
    971-2880, Nebraska

Comment: Why is there no `Nebraska` line in your expected output?  Would each line of your file potentially contain a different number of CSV entries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```py
df.address = df.address.str.split('\n')
df.explode('address')
```

You should get:

```
       name         address
0  711-2880         Mankato
0  711-2880           96522
0  711-2880  (257) 563-7401
1  971-2880              CA
1  971-2880             965
1  971-2880   (01) 563-7401
1  971-2880        Nebraska
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'explode'

Comment: Upgrade your pandas to 0.25

Comment: You should reassign your df to the output of explode, i.e. `df = df.explode('address')